# seleniumwire_options=None: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, seleniumwire

I am using selenium-wire to click a button using Chrome browser. Up until today, my code worked fine.  However, now I get the following error and I am not sure why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Scraping_fx.py", line 1, in <module>
from seleniumwire import webdriver
File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site- 
packages\seleniumwire\webdriver\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .browser import Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari  # noqa
File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site- 
packages\seleniumwire\webdriver\browser.py", line 14
def __init__(self, *args, seleniumwire_options=None, **kwargs):
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using python 2.7.16; selenium-wire 1.0.4.

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException,NoSuchElementException
import logging

def scrape_website(url):

    # Configure browser driver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--headless')

    #Instantiate driver and navigate to URL
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(url)
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Anaconda3 is a Python 3 library, isn't it? My money is on "version discrepancy".

Comment: selenium-wire 1.04 requires Python 3.4+.

Comment: Just confirmed here Python 3.7 accepts that parameter order syntax, but not 2.7. I am referring to having a kw arg between *args and **kwargs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see anything wrong with your code :)
But selenium-wire 1.0.4 requires Python 3.4+.

You can find all the info on pypi.org - [here](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/)

Comment: Yes, the problem was my python version.

Comment: The version 1.0.3 still has that "regular parameter after * parameter" problem. What version doesn't have that?